# LINQ Query Filling Listbox From WebService

Tags: c#, linq, web-services, listbox, win-universal-app

I have written a simple web service that allows me to insert into my SQL DB (that works fine) and retrieve information from my SQL DB(currently not working). I am trying to put the information into a list and then display that information into a listbox in a universal windows application. This the login I have:

**WEB SERVICE**

```
  [OperationContract]
  List<TBL_My_Info> FindInfo(string uid);

  public List<TBL_My_Info> FindInfo(string uid)
    {
        DataClasses1DataContext context = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        var res = from r in context.TBL_My_Info where r.User_Name == uid select r;
        return res.ToList();
    }
```

**UNIVERSAL WEB APPLICATION**

```
     private void btnView_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string s = txtNameFind.Text;
        this.Content = new Page1(s);
    }       

     public Page1(string s)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        LoadData(s);          
    }

    private async void LoadData(string s)
    {
        var client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        var res = await client.FindMyInfoAsync(s);
        articleMyInfoListBox.ItemsSource = res;
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListBox x:Name="articleMyInfoListBox"></ListBox>
</Grid>
```

I know that I need to have something like `myListBox.ItemSource = res;`, but res is not showing up as an option after `ItemSource`. I have referenced my Web Service with a using `using myapp.ServiceReference1;`.

So in short, what I am looking to do is fill the list box with the returned list of information, knowing that the information is coming from a web service....

If I am doing this the wrong way and there is a better way, please let me know. I have zero experience with LINQ, but a realm of experience with SQL. So of course, SQL would be preferable..

**Edit**

I am currently getting this returned in my Listbox

```
using InsertAppTest.ServiceReference1.TBL_My_Info;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods generated for the Service Client are asynchronous and return instances of `Task`, so you'll need to `await` them properly in order to actually get the "res" return value. Try something like this:

```cs
private void btnView_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     string s = txtNameFind.Text;
     this.Content = new Page1(s);
 }

public Page1(string s)
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    LoadData(s);
}  

private async void LoadData(string s)
{
    var client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
    var res = await client.FindInfoAsync(s);
    listBox.ItemsSource = res;
}
```

That should work, but there may be a better way to structure your async calls - I just don't know enough about what you're trying to accomplish.

**Edit**

Your XAML is going to have to have the DisplayMemberPath property set so that it knows what property on TBL_My_Info to display. Right now it is probably just doing a `ToString()` on each instance.

If `TBL_My_Info` looks like this:

```cs
public class TBL_My_Info
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then your XAML should look like this:

```xml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListBox x:Name="articleMyInfoListBox" DisplayMemberPath="Name"></ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Ok, so I debugged the code after placing your suggestion in and it is bringing in the data via the "res" variable, but not displaying it in the listbox. Rather, in the listbox it is displaying the using statement I have up at the top of my page "using myapp.ServiceReference1" and is appending the table to the end of the using statement... So in whole my list box is returning this "using myapp.ServiceReference1.TBL_My_Info"... I will post updated code above, along with the xaml of the listbox. Any advice?

Comment: The content of your List Box when it renders is literally the string "using myapp.ServiceReference1.TBL_My_Info"? That doesn't make sense. Did you set the DisplayMemberPath property of the List Box to the name of a property on the TBL_My_Info class?

Comment: Literally.... I posted my markup in my question as an edit... The variable "res" is bringing in the information though, so getting the info is done. It is just not displaying correctly...

Comment: Can you try to set the DisplayMemberPath property of the List Box to the name of a property on the TBL_My_Info class?

Comment: When you say property, do you mean a name of a column i am retrieving?

Comment: I see what you are saying now... What is textblock version of DisplayMemberPath property?

Comment: Yes. Each column in your database table should be getting mapped to a property in your C# class "TBL_My_Info". You need to tell your List Box which property/column it should be displaying. Can you update your question with the code for TBL_My_Info"? I don't know what you mean by "textblock version". I will update my answer which what your XAML should look like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95484/discussion-between-code-and-alexchardin).